# What is the degree of the given differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The given Differential Equations is :

$$(y''')^\frac{4}{3} + (y')^\frac{1}{5} + 4=0$$

It's fairly obvious that the order of this DE is 3 but my main concern is that how will we simplify the equation to get the degree.
I have taken the (y') term to the RHS and raised the equation to (power) 5. After that its becoming quite lengthy. Any help would be a lot appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: is a nonlinear equation of degree 3 the higuest derivative defines the rank and degree not the powers

Comment: The order is the number of highest derivative in a DE and hence that makes the order 3 and degree is the power of that term, Perhaps you wanted to say something else? could you please rephrase if thats the case

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible, you would need to rationalize the equation to make all the indices into integers. It looks like the equation needs to be raised to a power for which all terms would end up with an integral degree. See [this link](http://www.solitaryroad.com/c650.html).

If the equation is rearranged so that it has $-4$ on the RHS, then the LHS  raised to a power $N$ would contain terms of the form $\left(y'''\right)^{\frac{4k}{3}} \, \left(y'\right)^{\frac{N-k}{5}}$ for $k=0, \ldots, N$. I.e. the requirement would then be to find an $N$ so that both $\frac{4k}{3}$ and $\frac{N-k}{5}$ are integers for $k=0, \ldots, N$. This looks to me like it is not possible, i.e. it may not be possible to assign a degree to the equation.

Comment: Raising to the power 15 would further complicate the equation as when we'll solve the equation raised to the power 15 using binomial theorem, only the first term of (y''') would get an integer power but as we open the raised equation further not all powers of (y''') or (y') would be converted into integers and hence we wont be able to determine the degree.

Comment: Thanks, I agree and have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I really appreciate your valuable response, although I am skeptical too whether the degree would exist or not, but the source from where I have found the question has mentioned the answer to be 60 i.e. the degree of the DE is 60, maybe they are wrong but I just wanted to explore the possibility.

Comment: Not sure how to get a degree as $60$.
I could see how degree could be $20$, but only if the ODE were homogeneous. If we drop the constant, we get 
$\left(y'''\right)^{\frac{4}{3}} = -\left(y'\right)^{\frac{1}{5}}$, raising to the power of $15$ gives $\left(y'''\right)^{20} = -\left(y'\right)^{3}$. Perhaps the degree can be defined as the degree of the corresponding homogeneous ODE? Apologies, I'm drawing a blank on where the answer of $60$ comes from. Looking at some of the discussions on the web, it seems that perhaps there isn't a single agreed definition of the degree of an ODE?